# Can't upload data from json in javascript code using fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

i am trying to build a simple login page, i've got a really basic form in my html with a button that when pressed is going to pass the data to the javascript.
The javascript should validate the data using a json file that i uploaded.

This is the json:

```
{
"users": [
  {
    "username": "alice",
    "password": "secret"
  },
  {
    "username": "bob",
    "password": "p@ssword123"
  }
]
```

This is the class i am going to use as a model

```
export class User {
constructor(username, password) {
  this.username = username;
  this.password = password;
}

getName() {
  return this.username;
}

getAge() {
  return this.password;
}
```

This is the javascript code:

```
import { User } from './user.js';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    fetchUsers()
        .then(users => console.log(users))
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
});

function fetchUsers() {
fetch('users.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const users = data.users.map(user => new User(user.username, user.password));
        // console.log(users)
        return users
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

The problem is that if i try to log the users in the fetchUser function it logs them, if i try to do it after pressing the button it gives me this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
at HTMLButtonElement.

Why is that ?

Comment: fetchUsers function is not returning anything. what are you expecting?

Comment: Change `fetch('users.json')` to `return fetch('users.json')`